# jquery selection of child elements given status of sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

given a html such as:

```
<ul id="timesheetList">                                              
<li>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="bigcheck">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="hiddenId">73</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</li>
<li>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="bigcheck">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="hiddenId">44</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</li>
    <!-- the list goes on... -->
```

how can I select all the IDS ( in this case 44 and 73 ) for all the "checked" (whose status is checked) chechboxes whose class is "bigcheck" ?

thanks

Comment: I think there's maybe a lot more pressing issues with your logic before you need to ask this question. There are no IDs on the page for starters. Just p tags with the class hiddenId. They're two different things entirely.

Comment: yes, I need the paragraphs, I can work them out to get the IDs inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First get all the checked checkboxes. U can use

   $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function(){

   });

   1. Then, u need to get to the TD, using parentNode()
   2. Then, use nextSibling(), to reach immediate next TD.
   3. Then, TD.childNodes[1].innerHTML, will give u the result

Note: If u r using this approach, then ur structure should remain same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
var tds = $('td p.hiddenId').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parent().prev().children('input.bigcheck:checked').length != 0;
});
// tds contains the list of TDs matching your criteria
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var ids = [];
$("td > input.bigcheck:checked").each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).parent().next("td").children("p").text());
});
console.log(ids);
```

You should wait for answers that might offer you a complete solution that works, instead of accepting something that is just guidance